# How to ignore value after first decimal point first value if it is 0 else take it if greater than 0?

Tags: c#

I am having a value like below :

```
decimal val = 1.100;
```

Now what I am trying to do is if I am having 0 after first decimal point value then I want to take only 1.1 and ignore rest and if I am having 1.11 then I want to take whole 1.11

This is how I am thinking to do it:

1. Convert decimal to string.
2. Split string by dot.
3. Check if length is 2 and if second position is greater than 0 then take whole like 11 for decimal value 1.11 else if decimal is like this 1.10 then take 1.1 else take 1.0 in case of decimal 1.000

Sample input and output:

```
1.000 // output 1.0
1.100 // output 1.1
1.110 // output 1.11
1.111 // output 1.111
1.102 // output 1.102
```

But this is dirty logic which I want to avoid. Isn't there is any inbuilt way or better way to do this?

**Note:** I don't want to do any kind of round up.

Comment: What if value is 1.1045? what you want in this value

Comment: @Blue I will have only 3 decimal places so it will be like this 1.104 and in that case i want to take 1.104

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [custom numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings):

```
val.ToString("0.0##")
```

Comment: Yeah this worked.Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Comment: Thank you for your kind words.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you like this logic. Please try this.

```
  double val = 1.002;
  string output = !val.ToString().TrimEnd('0').Contains('.') ? string.Format("{0}.0", val) : val.ToString().TrimEnd('0');
```

If the value is 1.00, then my output will be 1.0

Then you can convert this string into other data types.